# Selectors in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are selectors in objective - c just another way to send a message to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543137/are-selectors-in-objective-c-just-another-way-to-send-a-message-to-an-object)

I understand how the `@selector` syntax works, but can't figure out when they are useful. For example let's say I have class Person;

Person.h

```
@interface Person : NSObject

-(void)printPersonName;
@end
```

Person.m

```
@implementation Person

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(printPersonName)];
        [self printPersonName];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)printPersonName
{
    NSLog(@"My name is Steve");
}
@end
```

This snippet of code do the same thing

```
[self performSelector:@selector(printPersonName)];
[self printPersonName];
```

When is `@selector` useful?