# What is the need for selectors?

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are selectors in Objective-C just another way to send a message to an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543137/are-selectors-in-objective-c-just-another-way-to-send-a-message-to-an-object)

I've read Apple's documentation about selectors, but I still don't understand why there is a need for them.

As far as I can understand, selectors are equivalent to function pointers. Is that right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are selectors in objective - c just another way to send a message to an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543137/are-selectors-in-objective-c-just-another-way-to-send-a-message-to-an-object) and [Understanding selectors in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051528/issue-understanding-a-part-of-selectors-of-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

Selectors are used to obtain the method implementation of an object.

For example, almost every object implements the `description` method even if it inherits the implementation from its superclass. A function pointer can only point to one particular implementation of `description` (e.g. it can only point to NSString's version, or NSNumber's version, but not both). You can't take the function pointer of one class's `description` implementation and use it for every class, but you *can* use the same `description` selector, and it doesn't matter what object you use as the target, the right method implementation will always be used.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors are not function pointers.

Selectors are unique-address method identifiers (message names). They're needed for the messenger function (objc_msgSend_*()) to be fast: when looking up a method name, the messenger doesn't need to do the rather expensive string comparison every time, because a selector has a  unique address in memory, so a simple pointer comparison is enough.